# Deduping employee activity from user activity when measuring events with Mixpanel

Tags: javascript, mixpanel, website-metrics

I'd like to measure user engagement of my dashboard via Mixpanel. No experience with Mixpanel at all though, but People/Profiles looks like it could help me with this.

My problem is that right now in order to debug I log into a users' account as the user. I have a admin control panel with the facility to let me login the selected user account as the user etc. It is non-trivial to implement a superuser account for doing account maintenance.

Is there a way I can set up Mixpanel People/Profiles to screen out my activity as the user from the user's own activity? Maybe something ip based?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. The easiest is just to visit their opt out page on your computer/browser, which will prevent tracking for your browser sessions.

If you do need to test mixpanel logging after having opted out, you can visit the opt out page again and opt back in. Or in Firefox or Chrome you can use a private or incognito tab which won't have your opted out cookie information.

Source:
https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/can-i-exclude-myself-from-mixpanel-data